# Getting new records in a certain time frame

Tags: mysql, sql

My table design is somewhat like this.

```
id |    date    | user_id
1  | 2013-02-02 |  1
2  | 2013-02-02 |  2
3  | 2013-02-02 |  5
4  | 2013-02-03 |  6
5  | 2013-02-03 |  7
6  | 2013-02-03 |  1
```

Now I want to select records for only new user for a certain date or time frame. For example, if I select  `date=date('2013-02-03')`, I need only the records which are for new users i.e. record id 4 and 5 and should not return 6 as the user already have a record.

Simply, it should only return records of users which have no previous records on their user_id. I tried writing queries with not in operator, but I don't know how to give parameter for date less then the current record date.

[EDIT]

This is where I reached and where I am stuck.

```
select id from mytable where date=date('2013-02-03') and user_id not in (select user_id from mytable where date<date('2013-02-03'))
```

This works fine when for only one exact date. But when it comes to time frame, say for a month, I can't figure out how to get the inner query where date should be the date of record for that particular user.

[EDIT]

Tried this query with using having clause. Its returning empty result.

```
select id, date, user_id from mytable having min(date(date))>=date("2013-01-02") and min(date(date))<=date("2013-02-02")
```

ok I got the problem with this query. Its check min(date) out of over all records. How can I make this look for min record for each user_id?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: To be honest, tried searching google for the right way of doing so. Tried other ways of accomplishing my goal which is to generate a report. When I could not figure out the structure of the query and other ways to hit the goal, I asked here.

Comment: Did you try to actually write some SQL?

Comment: +1 For "What have you tried" and the lengthy post on professional courtesy.

Comment: Yes I did, obviously. Ok just a min, let me add it to my question.

Comment: Now back to the answer, the mysql keyword here is "having"

Comment: You should also stored time with date during registration or login.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy its actually not login puzzled boy. Its a customer relationship manager where I am tracking conversation tickets of customers. I don't need time here. Date works fine. Can we get back to  the real question?

Comment: @Ares: Am sorry but I still can't figure out what having can do here? As I just googled, conditions on 'having' clause also expects parameter value to be specific. :/ :/

Comment: Thankx.
its only my suggestion not my ans.. 
 and i don't know what is it. i only guess.

Comment: Yeah right. Thanks for the suggestion anyways. And sorry for being rude. I am messing up with this query from last 1 and a half hour. so, u knw.

Comment: how many record are you want in output?? in this case output should id =5 right???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2013-02-02 |       1 |
|  2 | 2013-02-02 |       2 |
|  3 | 2013-02-02 |       5 |
|  4 | 2013-02-03 |       6 |
|  5 | 2013-02-03 |       7 |
|  6 | 2013-02-03 |       1 |
|  7 | 2013-02-04 |       6 | <-- additional record for user_id 6
+----+------------+---------+
```

And you are trying to get new users in interval `2013-02-03 - 2013-02-04`

```sql
SELECT MIN(id) id, MIN(`date`) `date`, `user_id`
  FROM (
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE('2013-02-03') AND DATE('2013-02-04')
   AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
                         FROM mytable 
                        WHERE `date` < DATE('2013-02-03'))
       ) t
 GROUP BY user_id
```

That will be your output:

```
+------+------------+---------+
| id   | date       | user_id |
+------+------------+---------+
|    4 | 2013-02-03 |       6 |
|    5 | 2013-02-03 |       7 |
+------+------------+---------+
```

Here is working **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0636/2)**

Comment: No this isn't working as your inner most query is returning all rows for which date is less then the last date of the time frame which makes outer query not select any rows other then for the last date. :(

Comment: Not the last but first. See sqlfiddle provided.

Comment: Ok I read your updated answer and updated the fiddle with a few more records + changed the time frame of the query. Here is the new fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddfe9/1/0

Comment: Provide a link to updated sqlfiddle. It changes every time you change sqlfiddle.

Comment: This is returning results only for 2013-02-04 and 2013-02-05, but as you can see, there are new user records on 2nd and 3rd as well.

Comment: Yeah I edited my comment, i mistakenly hit enter while commenting.

Comment: You **forgot to change the date** in inner select. In that case it should be `2013-02-02` See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddfe9/2. In that case all users are new result set contains only unique with `min(id)` and `min(date)`

Comment: Yes this time I think we got it. Thanks a lot. :) :)

Comment: It was correct in the first place, but glad that it helped. And you're certainly welcome. Happy coding.